# unity 3d terrain flatten heightmap height uneditable

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made all my objects in blender, sketched out what classes I would need and had a good idea of most of the goals  I wanted for my game.  The plan was to create the terrain in unity, place all my blender objects on the terrain, add the unity fps controller then implement\attach the necessary scripts.

One problem.  Step one creating the terrain.  When I go to flatten heightmap I can't change the value in the height box.  **I try to set it to 40 but it always reverts back to one. Please help!** If it matters I'm trying for an island.  The idea being that if I raise the terrain I can reduce the height around the edges creating slopes and curves that will be covered in with water.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.  Not exactly sure what fixed it but I think it had something to do with prefabs,